# Cognito accounts created with admin_create_user can't log in. Is there a known fix?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm creating a backend tool to create some accounts in an AWS Cognito User Pool using Python and boto3. Creating accounts with CognitoIdentityProvider's admin_create_user seems to work fine, but when I attempt to log into our app with the new account I receive a 400 response with:

{"__type":"UserNotFoundException","message":"User does not exist."}

I have made sure that the user has in-fact been added to the cognito user pool and that the user is enabled.

I have also specified that the email address be verified automatically upon account creation.

Here is my account creation function:

```py
import boto3 

idp_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

# Redacted for stackoverflow example
user_pool_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 

response = idp_client.admin_create_user(
            UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
            Username=email,
            UserAttributes=[
                {
                    'Name': 'email',
                    'Value': email
                },{
                    'Name': 'email_verified',
                    'Value': 'true'
                }
            ],
            TemporaryPassword=generateSecureRandomString()
        )
```

I'd expect that as the account is successfully created in the Cognito user pool and that the account seems to be enabled and verified that this should result in an account that can sign-in.

Any light that can be shed on the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That code is perfectly fine. So it must be a problem with either the pool settings or the login flow.

In the pool settings, make sure it's set to log in with "email address or phone number" - not username.

In the login flow, are you using the hosted ui? It might be worth giving that a shot, because it will weed out any issues with your login code. Note that your user will be set as status "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD". I'm not sure what error cognito returns if you try to log someone in with your own code, but they have that set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Really appreciate the help! Reassurance that this code was good lead me to investigate the other moving parts in the system.

After digging into it, it ended up being a bug in our app sign in code. I was unknowingly stripping "." characters out of gmail addresses.

Comment: Good to hear! Yeah - i ❤️ modularisation - knowing that one part of a system is correct always helps me diagnose to